# Он пришёл домой весёлый(,) видимо ещё не зная, что таки случилось

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Он пришёл домой весёлый(,) видимо ещё не зная, что таки случилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю, в чëм ваши сомнения. Деепричастный оборот обособляется в любом случае, а вводное слово не отделяется от него запятой:

*Он пришёл домой весёлый, видимо ещё не зная, что таки случилось*.

Он не может быть связан со сказуемым хотя бы потому, что из-за слова *весëлый* перед ним стоит пауза. И из-за него оборот можно убрать, т. к. он необязателен из-за именной части.

Comment: Видимо –  вводное  слово. Приведите ссылку, что его можно присоединять к обороту.  Работаем без ПРАВИЛ и ССЫЛОК?

Comment: @Sharon Если вводное слово относится к обороту (какому угодно!), находясь в его начале или конце, не отделяем их запятой. Ссылку чуть позже дам, сейчас мало времени.

Comment: А мне нужна ссылка! Будьте любезны отвечать по правилам, иначе вас придется минусовать. Вводное слово не отделяется запятой по правилу, а не по рассуждениям.

Comment: Так я по правилу и говорю. Вот ссылка, 4-й пункт: http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=32 Два примера оттуда: _Покупатель медлит, __вероятно обдумывая__, что лучше выбрать для подарка; Они молча смотрели друг на друга, __быть может и без слов понимая__, в чём дело_.

Comment: Правило надо указывать, а ваши рассуждения там ни к чему.

Comment: А, вы уже ответили, что ли? Я не из ответа ссылку брал, если что. Я даже не сразу его заметил.

Comment: А в чем была проблема?  Автор вопроса с репутацией 4,774  не знал этого правила? Какие были трудности?  А мне-то казалось, что он правила хорошо знает, а обсуждает только проблемные вопросы.

Comment: @Sharon Вряд ли он НЕ знал об этом. К тому же запятую после ВИДИМО он не обозначил — значит, тем более знал. А почему у него возник вопрос, обособлять или нет, — этого я не знаю.

Comment: @Sharon Я думал, что он знает о том, что после ВИДИМО запятая не нужна, поэтому и не указал.

Comment: Возможно, он  он считал, что сам оборот имеет обстоятельственное значение и не обособляется.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно:

*Он пришёл домой весёлый, // **видимо ещё не зная**, /
что таки случилось.*

1. **[Розенталь, пункт 4](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)**

Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит **в начале или в конце** обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то **никаким знаком препинания** от оборота оно не отделяется: *Он погрузился в размышления, **видимо** производя в уме какие-то расчёты.*

2. Деепричастный оборот обозначает **действие**  и обособляется вместе с вводным словом (обстоятельственного значения там нет).
3. Две основы, деепричастный оборот.

Предложение делится **на два блока**, граница (и основная пауза в речи) **перед деепричастным** оборотом, там стоит запятая.

Comment: Кто-то уже плюс поставил. Ставлю второй. Ответ, хоть и  имеет косвенное отношение к вопросу, правильный по сути.

Comment: @Sharon Из Вашего ответа: "Деепричастный оборот **действие** и обособляется..." Думаю, *что-то* тут надо исправить...

Comment: Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Sharon, извините, пожалуйста, совсем непонятно, для чего пункт 1 в ответе? Об этом не спрашивалось, запятой в вопросе нет, у автора есть только сомнения насчёт обстоятельственного значения оборота. // Зачем здесь упоминание о блоках? Ну какие здесь блоки? Довольно простое предложение, осложнённое деепричастным оборотом со своим придаточным. В теме блоков ставятся сильные знаки (для того чтобы показать взаимосвязи больших частей), а не запятые.

Comment: 1. Принятый ответ Максима посвящён вводному слову, поэтому я указываю правило и даю ссылку  2. Пр обстоятельственное значение я говорю. 3. Возможно, автор думает, что основная граница пере союзом ЧТО, поэтому блоки не помешают в этом разобраться. Метод применяется и в простых предложениях, которые разделены на три части.  4. Если то не так, а вы проголосовали за ответ, то вы можете убрать голос (ответ исправлен).  5. В данном случае первая запятая является более сильным знаком, чем вторая. Поэтому вторая пауза фактически произносительная.

Comment: О двух блоках не надо говорить без особых причин, но видеть их желательного всегда (хорошая практика).

Comment: 1. Принятый ответ Максима **не** посвящён вводному слову. Там написано только это: "Деепричастный оборот обособляется в любом случае, а вводное слово не отделяется от него запятой". 2. Так основа ответа и должна заключаться в этом: нужна ли запятая перед оборотом. А у вас ответ начинается с необособления вводного. 3. Метод применяется не в простых предложениях, а в предлозениях, где хотя бы один из блоков является сложным. 4. Я не голосовал, убирать или минусовать нечего (я только за то, чтобы ответ был по существу). 5. С тем, что первая запятая сильнее, я согласен.

Comment: 6. Если пишете о блоках, давайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на Лопатина. Помните, вы не раз мне говорили, что мы даём ответы не только для того, кто спрашивает, а для всех участников и гостей сайта.

Comment: Спасибо за обвинительное заключение. Почему меня все критикуют? Я у oleedd это спрашивала. А он отвечал: кроме вас, все правильно отвечают.  Возможно. Сначала вы все дружите со мной и советуетесь, потом считаете равными (нечему больше учиться), а потом начинаете меня учить и поучать. Я  не знаю, что мне с этим делать Любое мое новое начинание встречается с неприязнью:  интонация, блоки, вставки? Зачем все это? Нам больше нравится тихая и спокойная жизнь.  За что мой ответ с деепричастным оборотом минусовали? Какая там ошибка? Никто не сказал. Просто так!

Comment: Ссылку на блоки? Давайте на каждое слово будем давать ссылку, я не против. Но пусть все дают такие ссылки, в том числе по грамматике. Теперь буду ссылки спрашивать. Качество вопросов еще надо проверить.  Восток или восток? В чем там проблема? Кто этого не знает, зачем спрашивать о таких элементарных вещах, если у тебя репутация 5К.

Comment: Да какое же это обвинительное заключение? Я и так уже сижу и боюсь что-то лишнее взболтнуть. А здесь пишу, чтобы вы обратили внимание на небольшие, по моему мнению, недочёты. // Учиться всегда есть чему. Равным себя не считаю (хотя мы все равны в этом поле). // Про минусовку с деепричастным оборотом не видел, не помню, дайте ссылку, посмотрю. // Про Леовопросы вопросы вообще молчу, согласен с вами на все сто, какой-то спам или троллинг.

Comment: Я лучше спать. Спокойной ночи)

Comment: Угу, до встречи! Хороших и новых, провидческих снов! Вы классная, и это неоспоримо!